# Sum of squares of the degrees of irreducible representations equals order of group (positive characteristic case)

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose $K$ is a splitting field for a finite group $G$ such that $p = \mathrm{char} K >0$ and $p \nmid |G|$. Let $\{\rho_1, \ldots, \rho_s\}$ be the set of all irreducible representations (up to equivalence) of $G$ over $K$ of degrees $d_1, \ldots, d_s$ respectively. Show that $$\sum_{i=1}^{s}{d_i^2}=|G|.$$

I'm aware of the general approach to proving this result for the case where $K$ is of characteristic $0$ but I'm struggling to see how the result may be proved for the positive characteristic case. Any help/guidance in this would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** This has been marked as a duplicate of: [Sum of squares of dimensions of irreducible characters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234557/sum-of-squares-of-dimensions-of-irreducible-characters?lq=1). This is **not quite the same question as in the link**, as the other question deals only with the characteristic $0$ case.

Comment: This depends a lot on how you prove the characteristic-$0$ case. If your proof does not use characters, then it will probably carry over to the $\mathrm{char}K=p\nmid\left|G\right|$ case. Maschke's theorem (still valid due to this condition) ensures that $G$-modules are semisimple, and Artin-Wedderburn works, assuming that your definition of semisimplicity is not the one using the trace form (which indeed is tailored only to characteristic $0$, as far as I recall, since it is secretly a definition of strong separability rather than semisimplicity).